# If-else clause in Python Statement

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to check the output of few functions and if there is no error I move to next function.
So I have added a while loop and few if statements to handle the errors:

```
success = True
    while success:
        err, msg = function1()
        if not err:
            err, msg = function2()
            if not err:
                err, msg = function3()
                if not err:
                    err, msg = function4()
                else:
                    print msg
                    success = False
            else:
                print "function2 fails"
                sucess = False
        else:
            print "function1 fails"
            success = False
```

Is it a better way to avoid if,else , how can I redesign the code for this purpose?

Comment: Not sure If I understand you correctly but it's called exception handling: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html. You can use try except around the functions and in the functions you can raise and exception if an error occurs.

Comment: What you want to do is replace where your returning `err` with a `raise` statement, such as `raise RuntimeError()`. Then wrap the function calls in a `try: ... except RuntimeError: ...` block.

Comment: Use exceptions, duh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A relatively simple way would be to create a list of functions and iterate through them:

```
functions = [function1, function2, function3, function4]
success = True
while success:
    for f in functions:
        err, msg = f()
        # If there's an error, print the message, print that the
        # function failed (f.__name__ returns the name of the function
        # as a string), set success to False (to break out of the while
        # loop), and break out of the for loop.
        if err:
            print msg
            print "{} failed".format(f.__name__)
            success = False
            break
```

I'm sure you could be much more fancy and create a custom iterator, etc, etc, etc (which might be a better solution if your actual needs are more complicated). But this should work, too.

If you're concerned about printing to STDERR instead of STDOUT, you can also use [the `warn` function in the `warnings` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
while True:
    for f in (function1, function2, function3, function4):
        err, msg = f()
        if err:
            print("%s failed, msg is %s" % (f.func_name, msg))
            break
    else:
        break
```

It executes each function in sequence. If one of them fails then the msg and function name is printed, and we break the `for` statement. When we break the for, the `else` is not executed. So there is one more repetition of the above cycle.

If every function runs successfully then we don't break and the `else` of `for` is executed. This breaks from `while True` and the program continues normally.